# How to add existing repository to source tree

Tags: user-interface, insert, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

I have done the following: 
1 - checked the Unity forum, 2 - Checked the atlassian website for guides and, 3 - checked the internet, 4 - Asked the aslassian team for updates.

Someone in the unity forum agrees that the guides are a bit old and only meant for mac users. I am a windows user and the guides there no longer matches whatever user interface windows users have. It can't be followed. Does anyone know how to use sourcetree? How to add my existing repository? You may download the latest version to see the user interface because I just downloaded it.

Comment: This site is intended to help solves specific development related problems, can you rephrase the question to ask a specific question? Please refer to the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 
Also there's this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lBdlh3AGSc

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you need to make sure that a ".git" folder is already in the same folder. Beware that you might not be able to see it, depending on the settings in Windows. With the exception that nothing is damaged / corrupted, get the sourcetree browser button to point to that folder and it should be able to open.

Note: The requirements to check any of this would be to learn git and git bash and already have knowledge on how to get repositories to github.com. If you do not have this knowledge, it might be difficult to understand the purpose of the ".git" folder.